# How JS syntax like var a = (xml code) works?

Tags: javascript, xml, jsx

I'm confused. How can this work? This piece of js script file is from working project.

```
var $mapsIfAlbum = (
  <section class="slide section" data-index="2" style={{top: mapsPos + '%', zIndex: mapsPos}}>
    <div class="maps">
      {info}
      <Maps />
    </div>
  </section>
);
```

May it be some kinda template engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't. That isn't JavaScript. It is [JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) and needs to be run through a preprocessor to convert it to JavaScript before you can use it.

Comment: Thanks! Now it have a sence.